# Least common multiple of n numbers, using recursion

Tags: python, function, recursion, random, numbers

I need to write a recursive function, which finds the least common multiple elements of the list with n length. 
My code:

```
import random

def random_num(n):
    return [random.randint(-20,20) for i in range(n)]

def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0: 
        return a
    else: 
        return gcd(b, a % b)

def my_nok(n,m):
    return (n/gcd(n,m))*m
```

The first problem is: my functions work only with two arguments, not with the whole list.

The second problem: i need to have the only one function for finding the least common multiple (my code contains two for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to recur through a list, such as the following.  If there are 2 elements in the list, do your normal LCM.  If it's longer, then recur on the list tail, and then do LCM with that result and the first element.

```
def lcm(in_list):
    if len(in_list) == 2:
        # Do your normal LCM computation here
    else:
        return lcm([in_list[0], lcm(in_list[1:]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem is, that i don't know how to compute the lcm in one function, in the example i used gcd and my_nok for doing this.

Comment: That's what search engines are for.  http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-find-the-least-common-multiple.html, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

you need to find to LCM of the whole list. let "l" be the LCM of the whole array and if we pick any 2 random numbers from array, they will have a LCM say "l1" and so on and so forth "l2","l3","l4".... the LCM of these will also be the LCM of the whole array.

```
# we can find LCM of two numbers by the basic prime factorizing method
# but i will use the idea that GCD(a,b) * LCM(a,b) = a*b
# and it is easy to find the GCD(a,b)=[GCD(a,a%b)or GCD(b,b%a)] depending on if a is bigger or b
# i have used this idea because factoring large numbers take time.
```

so my idea is you can use divide and conquer

```
def LCM_of_array(array):
    if len(array)==2:
        return LCM(a,b)
    else:
        return LCM( LCM_of_array(n[0:len(array)/2]) , LCM_of_array(n[len(array)/2:len(array)])
```

you can explicitly define LCM(a,b) or just add a few more line of codes in this only

Edit: Code

```
def nod(a, b):   #to find GCD
   if b == 0:
      return a
   else:
    if a>b:
        return nod(b, a % b)

    else:
        return nod(a,b%a)   
def nok(a, b):    #to find LCM of two numbers
    return a * b / nod(a, b)

def nok_of_array(n):    #function for LCM of array
    if len(n) == 2:
        return nok(n[0], n[1])
    else:
        return nok (nok_of_array(n[ 0:len(n)/2 ]) , nok_of_array( n [ len(n)/2 : len(n)]))
```

Comment: I wrote the code in the answer, can you look through it?

Comment: Error: Slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method

Comment: I tried a lot of things, but this didn't work correct

Comment: add int(len(n)/2) instead of len(n)/2
this code is working for me.

Comment: It gives an error, the function works only with len(n) == 2

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I could work out and it worked for me.

```
def findDivisor(number):
    if number%2 == 0:
        return 2
    elif number%3==0:
        return 3
    return number

def LCM(nums):
    lcm = 1
    while len(nums) > 0:
        minOfnums = min(nums)
        divisor = findDivisor(minOfnums)

        for x in range(0, len(nums)):
            Quotient = nums[x]/divisor
            Reminder = nums[x]%divisor
            if Reminder == 0:
                nums[x] = Quotient

        lcm*=divisor
        minOfnums = min(nums)
        if minOfnums == 1:
            nums.remove(minOfnums)
    return lcm
```

Answer (score 0):

My code, the last return doesn't work correct.

```
import random
def nod(a, b):
   if b == 0:
      return a
   else:
      return nod(b, a % b)
def nok(a, b):
   return a * b / nod(a, b)
def nok_of_array(n):
   if len(n) == 2:
      return nok(n[1], n[2])
   else:
      return nok(nok_of_array[0:len(n)/2], nok_of_array[len(n)/2:len(n)])
n = [random.randint(-20,20) for i in range(0, random.randint(1, 20))]
print(nok_of_array(n))
print(n)
```